# Feasible to install mongo-connector on separate server from mongo databases?

Tags: mongodb, connector

Does anyone know if its more feasible to install mongo-connector on its own server or to just have it running on one of the mongo database servers?  I currently have it running on a secondary mongo server and want to move it off the secondary server but I am not sure if it really matters.

Comment: Since this isn't a really a programming question, this should probably be moved elsewhere (DBA or ServerFault?).

Answer (score 0):

[Mongo Connector](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector) is just another client application connecting to your MongoDB server. You can install it wherever you like, as long as it is able to connect to your MongoDB server and whatever external system you're trying to feed data to.

Note: If Mongo Connector is matching a comparatively small selection of data in the [replication oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) to insert into your external system, it would make sense to keep this on the same secondary or node whose oplog is being monitored. Otherwise the Connector will be pulling the full oplog over the network, which may consume unnecessary bandwidth.